# How to change previous and next arrows in Fancybox 3 script?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I purchased Fancybox 3 and would just like to change the arrows used for previous and next to angle bracket type. I see no way to do this - the arrows are SVG code? I thought this would be in the options I could specify. Also, I am trying to create a circle behind the arrows rather than a square and this works for all other buttons but the arrows - on the arrows it is a distorted rounded shape. I tried changing the padding but this has unexpected results.

Comment: you should add sample code, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Tehre is an option `btnTpl` that contains templates for various elements, for example, `btnTpl.arrowLeft`  would be template for left arrow.